# TBLASTN error: Too many positional arguments

Tags: blast, linux

I was running tblastn using standalone blast2.9.0+ through Ubuntu Linux, to get the alignment result of a list of protein sequences for same species, against its complete genome file.

The command I was using:

`~/softwares/ncbi-blast-2.9.0+/bin/tblastn -query TBLASTNstring/882.Tstring -subject ../com_gen/*882*.fasta -outfmt "7 acc qacc pident qcovs evalue sstart send sframe" -max_hsps 1 -num_alignments 1 -out 882.blastout`

(Info update: The query file has more than 1 sequence but all are in fasta format; the subject file has only 1 sequence; there is only 1 file with "882" named in the folder)

And I received error from tblastn as follow:

```
Error:  (CArgException::eSynopsis) Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: ../com_gen/DP_882_DeVul_Hilde.fasta
```

All the sequences in both my query and subject sequence files are of two lines, the header line started with ">", followed with sequences.

I have checked both query and subject sequence files using `sed -n '0~2p' | grep -v -E '[[:alpha:]]'` to see if there exist special character or space within the sequence line, but the output of the results return nothing.

PS: the complete genome file contained of nucleotide sequences with only ATGC (I have checked using `grep -v "ATGC"`)

I ran the same command for other species as well and it worked fine. 
[image: Example of result]

Info Update: The screenshot above was example of the result for species with TaxID 196627.

I wondered what is the thing that went wrong here? And what else I can check on them?

Comment: How many files match the `../com_gen/*882*.fasta` glob? Can `-subject` take more than one file as an argument? Also, aren't you mixing query and subject? What is `TBLASTNstring/882.Tstring`? That doesn't look like a fasta file, could that be the target DB name?

Comment: `-subject` and `-query` only allow one fasta file as argument

Comment: @PeterMenzel I haven't run blasts in ten years now. Do the modern versions really accept fasta files as `-subject`? Do they create the DB on the fly? Don't you need to first build the DB from the fasta file?

Comment: Hi @terdon I'm sorry for not being clear enough in the description. I have just updated some info in the post which is relevant regarding your question. There is only one sequence file named `../com_gen/*882*.fasta` in my folder. (I was using * as the file name is quite long but certainly there is only 1 sequence file with the name of "882".) TBLASTNstring/882.Tstring is my query file which has more than one sequence but all in fasta format.

Comment: @PeterMenzel As far as I am concerned, blast can detect all sequences in a file given if they are in fasta format? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Anyway I just tried extracting one of the fasta sequences from the query file and ran it again against the genome. The same error still appear.